# On Linux: How to edit configuration file and Execute ^T

Tags: linux, terminal

I am in Terminal and I am trying to get Waydroid to work.

For VM’s I need to edit the configuration file.

In the bottom corner of the terminal it says ^T to execute. If I press ^ on my keyboard (german layout) it does nothing. If I press the ^ key in like a browser I have to press it twice and then it also does ^^ and not ^.

How can I fix this? Found nothing online.

Comment: Press shift after pressing ^

Comment: `^T` generally means `ctrl+t`.

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that you should pres `Ctrl+t` (holding the Ctrl-button whist pressing 't').

*(If you actually sometime need to write a single '^' on a keyboard layout with dead-keys, like a German layout, type '^' followed by space.)*